# Filtered search in complex structure

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of people with this kind of schema :

```js
{
    "id": 125018,
    "nom": "GALLA",
    "prenom": "patrick",
    "departement": 91,
    "comptes": [
        {"id": 83557, "type": "facebook", "login": "patrick"},
        {"id": 83558, "type": "google", "login": "patrick"},
        {"id": 83558, "type": "twitter", "login": "patrick"}
    ]
}
```

I would search people who have `departement` equals to *91* and boost the scoring of those who have a *google* account.

I tried this kind of request :

```js
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "term": { "departement": "91" } }
        ],
        "should" : [
            { "match" : { "comptes.1.type" : "google" } }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
        "boost" : 1.0
    }
}
}
```

But `comptes.1.type` or `comptes.*.type` is not doing a good match.

Do you have a better query syntax that find people who have a *google* account?

EDIT :

Yes, thank you niko : your search query works well !

The mistake was in my input query. We need to be careful about the PHP **json_encode** function that do not gave me the right input syntax. So search doesn't work as well...

PHP json_encode input syntax :

```js
{
    "id": 125018,
    "nom": "GALLA",
    "prenom": "patrick",
    "departement": 91,
    "comptes": {
        83557 : {"id": 83557, "type": "facebook", "login": "patrick"},
        83558 : {"id": 83558, "type": "google", "login": "patrick"},
        83559 : {"id": 83559, "type": "twitter", "login": "patrick"}
    }
}
```

good inpout syntax :

```js
{
    "id": 125018,
    "nom": "GALLA",
    "prenom": "patrick",
    "departement": 91,
    "comptes": [
        {"id": 83557, "type": "facebook", "login": "patrick"},
        {"id": 83558, "type": "google", "login": "patrick"},
        {"id": 83559, "type": "twitter", "login": "patrick"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even in a mutivalued field, you specify a relationship by a `parent.child`  notation e.g `comptes.type` in your case.

To test this, you can try to find the users with a Google account:

```js
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "term": { "departement": 91 } },
            { "term": { "comptes.type": "google" } }
        ]
    }
}
```

A demo to play with https://www.found.no/play/gist/90a9290e806226e2d41f

and so your boosted query could look like

```js
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "term": { "departement": 91 } }
        ],
        "should" : [
            { "term" : { // you're looking for an exact term 
                "comptes.type" : {
                    "value": "google",
                    "boost": 2.0 
                }
            }}
        ]
    }
}
```

https://www.found.no/play/gist/ac979072963875ba79f9

The `boost` attribute is not necessary as Elastic will automatically boost the matching items but that can come in handy.